# Are all laptop DDR3 RAM sticks the same length, width and height?

Tags: laptop, memory

I am looking to buy RAM for my laptop, but when I went to Amazon I noticed that different DDR3 laptop RAM sticks have different dimensions. For example, image 1 and image 2 show the technical details of two different Kingston 4GB DDR3 RAM sticks, but the RAM sticks have different Product Dimensions and different Item Dimensions (length, width & height).

<sub>**Image 1**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Image 2**</sub>
[image]

How does this work? Do RAM sticks physical dimensions have anything to do with the way that they fit in all laptops?

Comment: The dimensions of DDR3 memory are not standard.  With that said DDR3 is DDR3, likewise SO-DIMM DDR3 is SO-DIMM DDR3.

Comment: Determine the dimensions of your current memory.  That is the best way to determine which modules you should purchase.  Be sure your providing us SO-DIMM module specifications.  A half inch difference seems in the length and width seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

Ram form factors are standardized, though typically there's two common standards per ram standard - SODIMM for laptops and small form factor systems, and regular ram.

Looking up the model numbers they're both SODIMM, though the former is 'regular' ram while the second one is low voltage ram, and premium branded (They slap a heat spreader on this).

My reasonably educated guess is that the Product and Item Dimensions are for *shipping* and are the size of the *packaging*. The regular ram probably comes in a clamshell, and the other ram comes in a box. Looking up both models confirms they are SODIMM.

That said, one of these ram types is *incorrect* depending on the system. Some systems will *only* work with low voltage ram. Mixing low and high voltage ram may work *if* the system supports it, though the low voltage ram will be running at a higher voltage, negating many of the advantages of it.

A good rule of thumb is to try to match the ram you have.

Comment: I'd pull the part about "ValueRam" unless  you have evidence to support it. I've used budget ram from multiple vendors and never been an issue. There arent any capacitors on DIMMs so they dont tend to "wear" out like a mobo would have write caps like an SSD.

Comment: I prefer to leave it as it is, since it's in the edit history anyway for whoever wants to read about it.